# Dell XPS 13 Ultrabook, WiFi N performance is slow and has problems

Tags: wireless-networking, dell-xps, 802.11n, ultrabook

I just opened a brand new [Dell XPS 13 Ultrabook](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-13-l321x/pd) and connected to my 802.11n wireless network.

Performance is abysmal. Web pages time out, [SpeedTest](http://www.speedtest.net/) shows 0.15 Mbps (on a 50 Mbps [FiOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verizon_FiOS) connection), and the ping between my computer and the wireless router is between 700 and 3000 milliseconds.

Oddly, connection to a 802.11g network works flawlessly. What's wrong?

Comment: Was this using the Developer Edition running Ubuntu or the regular one with Windows?

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that upgrading the Intel Wireless driver (Centrino Advanced-N 6230) from version 15.1.0 to 15.2.0 fixes the problem.

[image]

Visit this page to automatically detect your current driver version and install a new driver:

http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/wireless

Comment: Yes, this is a very specific question/answer, but the current top Google results are *completely* misguided. ("Reinstall your operating system"?!) so I am hoping this page eventually replaces those in Google.